# React Native deploys old version of App build instead of a new one

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, fastlane

### Problem

I am using [Fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/) to build and deploy my *React Native* app to *App Center* (Android). But it seems like it is stuck on one specific old version and all my changes in development are never showing up.

### Code

This is the lane I use to deploy:

```
  lane :beta do
    ensure_git_status_clean
    bump
    store_password = ENV['KEYSTORE_PASSWORD']
    releaseFilePath = File.join(Dir.pwd, '..', 'my-release-key.keystore')


    gradle(task: 'clean')
    gradle(
      task: 'bundle',
      build_type: 'Release',
      properties: {
        'android.injected.signing.store.file' => releaseFilePath,
        'android.injected.signing.store.password' => store_password,
        'android.injected.signing.key.alias' => 'my-key-alias',
        'android.injected.signing.key.password' => store_password
      }
    )

    appcenter_upload(
      owner_type: 'organization',
      mandatory_update: true,
      api_token: ENV['TEST_APPCENTER_API_TOKEN'],
      owner_name: ENV['TEST_APPCENTER_OWNER_NAME'],
      app_name: ENV['APPCENTER_APP_NAME'],
      file: './app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab',
      notify_testers: true,
      destinations: 'Mio',
      release_notes: changelog_from_git_commits
    )
  end
```

### Misc

I checked whether the old build is deleted. Every time the script runs, the build folder gets removed via `gradle(task: "clean")` and a new one gets generated. So why is my old code still showing up? This is driving me completely mad. I tried searching my files for the old code, but couldn't find it anywhere. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution to this? We're experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Not really, I switched to generating the bundles per Hand and uploading them without Fastlane :-(

Answer (score 2):

Ok so we found a solution for our problem - hopefully this will help you and/or others with similar issues.

Our problem was that our index.android.bundle file (found in /android/app/src/main/assets/) wasn't updated hence not pushed to AppCenter along with the other code changes. We noticed this by first deleting the file and then running this command in terminal:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

and seeing a git-diff in the index.android.bundle-file. After pushing these changes to Azure Devops and AppCenter the .apk installed on device actually contained the latest changes.

Comment: Do you know why it wasn't updated?

Comment: For us the file didn't update because we didn't build our solution (locally) with the _same variant_ ("qa" in our case) as AppCenter before pushing our code. Based on my understanding of the index.android.bundle-file it basically represents the complete (android) app bundled "as" JS and therefor must be up to date. Please mark my reply as an answer if it helped you with your problem.